# Error while running watir webdriver script for Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

I am running below script for Chrome 
but its showing me error while running script

require 'watir-webdriver'

```
b = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').set 'your name'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').select 'Ruby'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').selected? 'Ruby'
b.button(:name => 'submit').click
b.text.include? 'Thank you'
```

Getting below error for running script

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdr
iver/chrome/service.rb:19:in `executable_path': Unable to find the chromedriver
executable. Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromedrive
r/downloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.g
oogle.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverEr
ror)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the error message says it all. You have to install chromedriver:

https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/manuscript/installation/windows.md#chrome

Comment: hi i installed driver but while running script its showing error asC:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/platform.rb:27
: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Started ChromeDriver
port=53897
version=20.0.1133.0
log=D:\chromedriver.log
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': An existing co
nnection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Comment: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.9-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/platform.rb:27
: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

Comment: You will have to provide more data. I suggest you create another question for this new problem.

Comment: The new error shows that you now have chromedriver installed, and it is findable via the PATH on the system.  So now your problem has changed, time for a new question relating to the new error.

Comment: Thanks for comment i already added new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783879/script-running-on-chrome-showing-errors#comment14036136_10783879

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin: Unfortunately the link you have provided is broken. 404 error

Comment: You are welcome  Željko Filipin. Yes, the link is working well now

Answer (score 1):

You have to install/configure ChromeDriver. The following are the steps:

1. Download chromedriver if you want to use google chrome for testing (recommended) from: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html (I downloaded 2.13 version for Windows7)
2. Place in your PATH as follow:
   **Ubuntu:** usr/bin
   **Windows:** The ruby install folder is a good place, (usually C:/ruby###)/bin

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, I found that not all PATH directories worked. Pasting the file in this path (folder), however, did work for me (make sure its called 'chromedriver', not 'chromedriver2'! (happened b/c of duplicate download)

/Users/[mac_account_name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/

Obviously, I use rvm.

(be sure to restart the shell after you add it to pick up the changes)